# AngularJS passing data between controllers

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to pass data between controllers. Can someone please help me out?

This is the entirety if my angularjs file:

```
    var app = angular.module('FitnessApp', []);

var HTTP_RESPONSE = function(response) { return response.data || response; };
var HTTP_ERROR    = function(err) {return err; };

app.service('Share', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  var user = null;
  var viewUser = null;
  return {
    setUser: function(newUser)  {user = newUser; return $rootScope.$broadcast('user:updated'); },
    getUser: function()         {return user;},

    setSearchedUser: function(searchedUser)  {
      viewUser = searchedUser; console.log(viewUser);

      $timeout(function(){
         return $rootScope.$broadcast('user:searched');
      }, 5000);

      //return $rootScope.$broadcast('user:searched'); 
    },
    getSearchedUser: function()         {return viewUser;}
  };
}]);

app.service('UserFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
    // checkUserExists: function(user) {
    //   return $http.get('/user/exists', user).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    // },
    /*updateRating: function(id, rating) {
      return $http.put('/user/updateRating', {_id: id, rating: rating}).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },*/
    userLogIn: function(user) {
      return $http.post('/user/login', user).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    getUser: function(user_id) {
      return $http.get('/user/userProfile/' + user_id).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    userSignup: function(user) {
      return $http.post('/user/adduser', user).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    userEdit: function(user) {
      return $http.put('/user/updateUser', user).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    userChangeEmail: function(user) {
      return $http.put('/user/changeEmail', user).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    userChangePassword: function(user) {
      return $http.put('/user/changePassword', user).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    userDelete: function(del) {
      return $http.put('/user/deleteUser/', del).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    /*trainerLogin: function(trainer) {
      return $http.post('/trainer/login', trainer).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },*/
    trainerSignup: function(trainer) {
      return $http.post('/trainer/addTrainer', trainer).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },


    findUser: function(email) {
      return $http.get('/user/findByEmail/' + email).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    updateRating: function(idUser, idViewed, rating) {
      return $http.put('/user/updateRating', {_id_user: idUser, _id_viewed: idViewed, rating: rating}).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    getRating: function(idUser, idViewed) {
      return $http.put('/user/getRating', {_id_user: idUser, _id_viewed: idViewed}).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    }

  };
}]);


// service that contains the ajax query
app.service('TrainerFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    trainerAddEvent: function(trainerEvent) {
      return $http.post('/trainer/addEvent', trainerEvent).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);

    }
  };
}]);

// controller which injects the above service
app.controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'TrainerFactory', 'Share', function($scope, TrainerFactory, Share) {
  $scope.trainerAddEvent = function(newEvent) {
    TrainerFactory.trainerAddEvent(newEvent).then(function(response) {

        window.location.replace('/');

    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {});
  };
}]);


app.controller('RootController', ['$scope', '$window', 'UserFactory', 'Share', function($scope, $window, UserFactory, Share) {

  $scope.initUser = function(user_id) {
    UserFactory.getUser(user_id).then(function(response) {
      Share.setUser(response);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }).finally(function(){});
  };

  $scope.$on('user:updated', function(data) {
    $scope.user = Share.getUser();
  });

  $scope.findUser = function(email) {
    UserFactory.findUser(email).then(function(response) {

        switch(response.status) {
            case 200:

              Share.setSearchedUser(response.data);

              // gets the user object from users.js '/user/findByEmail/:email'
              // $scope.viewUser = response.data;

              // $scope.showme = true;

              // // gets the user's average rating
              // $scope.userAverage = response.data.rating;

              //********************************************************************* this will need to change when we go live
              $window.location.href = "http://10.0.0.25:8001/user/profile/";

              break;
            case 404:
              // User not found
              $scope.login_err = 'Email not found, please try again';
              break;
            default:
              $scope.login_err = 'An unexpected Error has occurred, please try again later.';
        }

    }, function(err) {

    }).finally(function(){});
   };

}]);

app.controller('ViewProfileController', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', 'Share', function($scope, SearchFactory, Share) {

  $scope.viewUser = Share.getSearchedUser(); console.log($scope.viewUser);

  // gets the current user
  $scope.$on('user:updated', function(data) {
    $scope.user = Share.getUser();
  });

  $scope.$on('user:searched', function(data) {console.log('here');
    $scope.viewUser = Share.getSearchedUser(); console.log($scope.viewUser);
  });

 $scope.updateRating = function(idUser, idViewed, rating) {
      UserFactory.updateRating(idUser, idViewed, rating).then(function(response) {

        // update rating for front end
        $scope.userAverage = response.data;

      }, function(err) {

      }).finally(function() {});
  };

  $scope.getRating = function(idUser, idViewed) {
      UserFactory.getRating(idUser, idViewed).then(function(response) {

        // relay the current user's rating of the user being viewed
        console.log(response.data);
        $scope.rating = response.data;

      }, function(err) {

      }).finally(function() {});
  };

}]);

app.controller('SignupController', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', 'Share', function($scope, UserFactory, Share) {
  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    console.log('hello!');
  };

  $scope.$on('user:updated', function(data) {
    $scope.user = Share.getUser();
  });

  $scope.clearMessages = function(messages) {
    messages.forEach(function(message) {
      message = null;
    });
  };
  // Login
  $scope.userLogin = function(user) {
    UserFactory.userLogIn(user).then(function(response) {
      switch(response.status) {
        case 200:
          // Okay to proceed
          window.location.replace('/');
          break;
        case 406:
          // Okay to proceed
          window.location.replace('/newTrainer');
          break;
        case 404:
          // User not found
          $scope.login_err = 'Email not found, please try again';
          break;
        case 401:
          // Password incorrect
          $scope.login_err = 'Incorrect password, please try again';
          break;
        case 400:
          // Invalid request
          break;
        default:
          $scope.login_err = 'An unexpected Error has occurred, please try again later.';
      }
    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {
    });
  };

  // Signup
  $scope.userSignup = function(user) {
    UserFactory.userSignup(user).then(function(response) {
      switch(response.status) {
        case 200:
          // Okay to proceed
          window.location.replace('/');
          break;
        case 401:
          // User already exists
          $scope.signup_err = 'Email unavailable or invalid, please try again';
          return;
        case 400:
          // Invalid Request
          $scope.signup_err = 'An Error has occurred, please contact support@smb.com for help.';
          break;
        default:
          $scope.signup_err = 'An unexpected Error has occurred, please try again later';
      }
    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {});
  };

  $scope.trainerSignup = function(newTrainer) {
    UserFactory.trainerSignup(newTrainer).then(function(response) {
        switch(response.status) {
            case 200:
              // Okay to proceed
              window.location.replace('/newTrainer');
              break;
            case 401:
              // User already exists
              $scope.signup_err = 'Email unavailable or invalid, please try again';
              return;
            case 400:
              // Invalid Request
              $scope.signup_err = 'An Error has occurred, please contact support@smb.com for help.';
              break;
            default:
              $scope.signup_err = 'An unexpected Error has occurred, please try again later';
      }
    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {});
  };
}]);

app.controller('ProfileController', ['UserFactory', 'Share', '$scope', function(UserFactory, Share, $scope) {
  $scope.$on('user:updated', function() {
    $scope.user = Share.getUser();
  });

  /*$scope.updateRating = function(id, rating) {
    return UserFactory.updateRating(id, rating).then(function(response) {
      //$scope.user.rating.push(rating);
    }, function(err) {

    }).finally(function() {});
  };*/

  $scope.updateUser = function(updatedUser) {
    return UserFactory.userEdit(updatedUser).then(function(response) {
      $scope.message = 'Success!';
    }, function(err) {

    }).finally(function() {});
  };
  $scope.changeEmail = function(updatedUser) {
    return UserFactory.userChangeEmail(updatedUser).then(function(response) {
    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {});
  };

  $scope.changePassword = function(updatedUser) {
    return UserFactory.userChangePassword(updatedUser).then(function(response) {
    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {});
  };

  $scope.deleteUser = function(user) {
    UserFactory.userDelete(user).then(function(response) {
      switch(response.status) {
        case 200:
          window.location.replace('/user/signup');
          break;
        case 404:
          $scope.del_err = 'Wrong Email, please try again';
          break;
        default:
          $scope.del_err = 'An unexpected error occurred, please try again later';
      }
    }, function(err) {}).finally(function() {
      console.error(err);
    });
  };
}]);

app.service('ActivityService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    addActivity: function(activity) {
      return $http.put('/user/addActivity', {activity: activity}).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    removeActivity: function(activity) {
      return $http.put('/user/removeActivity', {activity: activity}).then(HTTP_RESPONSE, HTTP_ERROR);
    },
    hasInterest: function(activity, array) {
      var found = false;
      array.forEach(function(interest) {
        found = found || activity === interest;
      });
      return found;
    }
  };
}]);

app.controller('ActivityController', ['$scope', 'Share', 'ActivityService', function($scope, Share, ActivityService) {
  $scope.$on('user:updated', function() {
    $scope.user = Share.getUser();
  });

  $scope.addActivity = function(activity) {
    return ActivityService.addActivity(activity).then(function(response) {
      $scope.user.activities.push(activity);
    }, function(err) {

    }).finally(function() {});
  };
  $scope.removeActivity = function(activity) {
    return ActivityService.removeActivity(activity).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.user.activities = $scope.user.activities.filter(function(act) {
        console.log(act, activity);
        return activity !== act;
      });
    }, function(err) {

    }).finally(function() {});
  };
  $scope.hasInterest = function(interest) {
    return ActivityService.hasInterest(interest, $scope.user.activities);
  };

}]);

app.service('MapService', function() {
  return  {

  };
});
app.controller('MapController', ['$scope', 'Share', 'MapService', function($scope, Share, MapService) {

}]);
```

I am trying to pass information about the user object from the RootController to the ViewProfile Controller.

I think a problem I may be having is that switching the view may be destroying the variable?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is layout.jade which uses RootController:

```
    doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/jquery.datetimepicker.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stylesheets/ratings.css')

    block loadfirst
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js')
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js')

    script(src='/angular/fitnessapp.js')

  body
    div#wrapper(ng-app='FitnessApp')
      div#header(ng-controller='RootController' ng-init='initUser(#{JSON.stringify(user)})')
        nav.navbar.navbar-default
          div.container-fluid
            // Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display
            div.navbar-header
              button.navbar-toggle.collapsed(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1', aria-expanded='false')
                span.sr-only Toggle navigation
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
                span.icon-bar
              a.navbar-brand(href='/') SpotMeBro
            // Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
            div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
              ul.nav.navbar-nav
                li.dropdown
                  a.dropdown-toggle(href='#', data-toggle='dropdown', role='button', aria-haspopup='true', aria-expanded='false')
                    | Dropdown
                    span.caret
                  ul.dropdown-menu
                    li
                      a(href='#') {{user.type}}
                    li
                      a(href='#') Another action
                    li
                      a(href='#') Something else here
                    li.divider(role='separator')
                    li
                      a(href='#') Separated link
                    li.divider(role='separator')
                    li
                      a(href='#') One more separated link
              form.navbar-form.navbar-left(role='search')
                .form-group
                  input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Search for an event')
                button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
              ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                if(!user)
                  li
                    a(href='/user/signup') Login/Signup
                  li
                    a(href='/trainer/signup') Trainer Signup
                else
                  li
                    a(href='/user/search/') Search 
                  li
                    a(ng-if='user.type' href='/trainer/createEvent') Create Event 
                  li
                    a(href='/user/profile/') Profile
                  li
                    a(href='/user/interests') Interests
                  li
                    a(href='/user/settings') Settings
                  li
                    a(href='/logout') Logout

              div
                form.navbar-form.navbar-right(name='search' ng-submit="search.$valid && findUser(email);" novalidate)

                  div.form-group
                    div.input-group
                      input#email.form-control(name='email' ng-model='email' type='email' required)
                    button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Search 

                  div(ng-show='search.$submitted')
                      span.text-danger(ng-show='search.email.$error.required')
                        | Please enter an email.
                      span.text-danger(ng-show='search.email.$error.email')
                        | Please enter an email.



          // /.navbar-collapse
        // /.container-fluid
      div#body
        block content

    div#footer
      div.container-fluid.text-center
        span.text-center F&uuml;tr
    block scripts
```

And here is userProfile.jade which uses ViewProfileController:

```
extends layout

block content
  div.container(ng-controller='ViewProfileController') 
    //- legend Search for user by email
    //- form(name='search' ng-submit='search.$valid && findUser(email)' novalidate)

    //-   div.form-group
    //-     div.input-group
    //-       label(for='Email') Email
    //-       input#email.form-control(name='email' ng-model='email' type='email' required)

    //-   div(ng-show='search.$submitted || search.email.$touched')
    //-       span.text-danger(ng-show='search.email.$error.required')
    //-         | Please enter an email.
    //-       span.text-danger(ng-show='search.email.$error.email')
    //-         | Please enter an email.

    //-   div.form-group
    //-     button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Search 

    div
        legend {{viewUser.firstName}} {{viewUser.lastName}}'s Profile {{user.email}} {{viewUser.email}}

          div
            span Email: {{viewUser.email}}
            br
            span Join Date: {{viewUser.joinDate}}            

          div
            //img(src= "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/8c70c2b66b7a52154bb3d3faadf03995c2c1e5ca0144a8979c834e61a1e166f5_1.jpg" width="250" height="250")
            img(src= "http://us.123rf.com/450wm/arcady31/arcady311212/arcady31121200002/16708573-anonymous-vector-sign.jpg" width="250" height="250")

          div(ng-if='showme===true')
            div(ng-init='getRating(user._id, viewUser._id)')

          div#star-div {{viewUser.firstName}}'s average rating: {{userAverage}}
            br
            div(ng-if='user.email != viewUser.email')
              span.star-rating
                input(ng-change='updateRating(user._id, viewUser._id, rating);' ng-model='rating' type='radio', name='rate', value='1')
                i
                input(ng-change='updateRating(user._id, viewUser._id, rating);' ng-model='rating' type='radio', name='rate', value='2')
                i
                input(ng-change='updateRating(user._id, viewUser._id, rating);' ng-model='rating' type='radio', name='rate', value='3')
                i
                input(ng-change='updateRating(user._id, viewUser._id, rating);' ng-model='rating' type='radio', name='rate', value='4')
                i
                input(ng-change='updateRating(user._id, viewUser._id, rating);' ng-model='rating' type='radio', name='rate', value='5')
                i
            br

          div Interests
            br 
            label.label.label-default {{viewUser.activities}}
            br

          div Member Since
            br 
            label.label.label-default {{viewUser.joinDate}}
            br

          div About Me
            br
            label.label.label-default {{viewUser.about}}
            br

          div RSVP'D Activities
            br
            label.label.label-default {{viewUser.upcomingActivities}}
            br

          div Past Activities
            br
            label.label.label-default {{viewUser.pastActivities}} 
            br
```

Comment: I assume that the route `user/profile/` is the one using `ViewProfileController`?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is correct.

Comment: Just for testing, increase the timeout inside `setSearchedUser` to 5000 and see what happens.

Comment: I had alreay tried that. It did not change anything.

Comment: While I see many flaws in your current design, it should work as long as the profile page loads and the controller is initialised before the timeout inside `setSearchedUser` executes. I made an isolated test and confirmed.

Comment: Is `console.log('here')` executed at all?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your isolated test with me? I can not get mine to work no matter what timeout I use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113673/discussion-between-tassekatt-and-rgins16).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current navigation every time you navigate to a page the HTML sent back from the server will include everything from `layout.jade`.

Since this contains `ng-app` your application will restart and everything will be reset, including the variables in your service.

I recommend that you look into [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) instead for navigation.

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me.